# What regex should i use to validate a number pattern?

Tags: javascript, validation

For this first validate I try to validate an input of 4 digits, however when i try to run it and enter 4 digits the error still shows up:

```
function pCodeValidate() {
    var pCode = document.getElementById("postcode");
    var pCodePattern = /^\d{4}$/;
    if (!(pCodePattern.test(pCode))){
        errorList("post code must be 4 digits")
    } 
    //return
}
```

The second one validates a mobile number with the pattern "04dddddddd, where d is a digit". this is my code:

```
function mNumberValidate() {
    var mNumber = document.getElementById("mobilenumber");
    var mNumberPattern = /^\d{10}$/;
    if (!(mNumberPattern.test(mNumber))){
        errorList("invalid mobile number");
    }
    //return
}
```

For this second part what regex should I use to enforce "04" being the first value in the input?

Comment: @zb just for my own knowledge could you explain to me how to interpret that regex?

Comment: @timolawl yes, really

Comment: yes, I edited comment :)

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/r/XTr0bmIUiwvvkp-o

Comment: @zb thank you, i get it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first function is that you are not using the regex to test the *value* of the input, you are trying to test a reference to the input itself. Change the following line:

```
var pCode = document.getElementById("postcode");
```

to get the value:

```
var pCode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
```

In your second function you have the same problem, which you'd fix the same way:

```
var mNumber = document.getElementById("mobilenumber").value;
// --------------------------------- add this part >-^^^^^^
```

Then the regex you need for a phone number starting with `04` is as follows:

```
/^04\d{8}$/
```

That is:

```
^     - beginning of string
04    - the literal characters "04"
\d{8} - any 8 digits
$     - end of string
```

(Dodgy demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xah6qstz/)

Comment: thank you very much for the clear explanation. This solved it